# Tchau é usado fora do Brasil?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, português-europeu

Tenho trabalhado com colegas italianos que utilizam o *Ciao*. Fiquei curioso e procurei a origem dessa palavra em Português.

Vi [aqui](https://www.significadosbr.com.br/tchau) que ela teve origem no Brasil por conta da imigração italiana e sua grafia aportuguesada “tchau” surgiu em 1925 no dicionário Houaiss. Pesquisei um pouco e vi alguns comentários que em algumas regiões de Portugal é usado também.

"Tchau" é realmente é usado em Portugal ou é uma palavra do Português do Brasil?

Comment: A primeira edição do dicionário Houaiss é de 2001, logo *tchau* não pode ter surgido em 1925 no dicionário Houaiss.  O que deves querer dizer é que de acordo com o dicionário Houaiss, *tchau* surge em 1925.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sim, *tchau* é muito comum em Portugal. Já a vi escrita *tchau, txau, chau, xau* e até mesmo *ciao*, à italiana. Como é uma palavra muito mais falada do que escrita, e muito informal, imagino que na hora de escrever, cada um escreve como lhe dá na telha. *Tchau* e *chau* são as formas dicionarizadas, quer no Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa (2001), quer no [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/chau) e [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/chau).

Comment: Curioso, não me lembro de alguma vez ter visto "tchau" nem "txau".

Comment: No Brasil, escrevemos tchau. Essa é a grafia aceita.

Comment: @ANeves Eu como vejo a tão pouco a palavra escrita fui ver à net, só de Portugal, e é precisamente *tchau* e *txau* que encontrei mais. Mas pronuncias como se fosse *tchau*? Ou não pronuncias o *t*?

Comment: @Peixoto, sim eu fui ver ao Aulete e Michaelis, e só encontrei *tchau*. O Huaiss é que tem os dois também. Eu acho que cá em Portugal foi por brincadeira que algumas pessoas começaram a dizer *chau*.

Comment: Não pronuncio, @Jacinto. (E escrevo com x.)

Comment: Ah, tu que és do norte não pronuncias o *t*; eu que sou do sul, pronuncio-o, tal como a maioria do pessoal daqui. Bem me parecia que [este artigo do Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/ciao--chau/12750) era treta.