# Desde quando o termo "tchau" passou a ser utilizado em Portugal? Qual o pais de origem?

Tags: significado, português-europeu, origem-histórica, origem, estrangeirismos

Desde quando o termo "tchau" passou a ser utilizado em Portugal?

Comment: Será que você não sabe que é ciao do italiano?? O voto negativo: não fui eu.

Comment: Fiquei a saber. Mas parece que primeiro foi ao brasil , para depois chegar a Portugal.  Será?!

Comment: Não penso que iria transitar primeiro pelo Brazil. Porque? Todo mundo na Europa usa o termo....

Comment: O voto positivo foi meu e é uma boa pergunta.

Comment: Muitos italianos emigraram para o Brasil

Comment: Relacionada: [Tchau é usado fora do Brasil?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/4459/2764).

Answer (score 2):

O Houaiss data a introdução do termo no português do Brasil em 1925, vindo de "dialetos do norte da Itália", muito provavelmente [trazido](https://www.significadosbr.com.br/tchau) por imigrantes italianos.

Em Portugal, "tchau" é dicionarizado há decadas e Jacinto [escreve em 2017](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/4461/2764) que o termo já era então de uso muito comum. Contudo, sua adoção não se deu sem resistência, como essa [postagem](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/xautchau-ou-adeus-ate-logo/11981#) no Ciberdúvidas de um professor de português em Portugal atesta:

> Não obstante a sonoridade de ciao, parece-nos que possuímos muitas outras formas de despedida, sem declararmos o nosso servilismo.

Postagem essa, no entanto, já revisada pelo editor, em 2017, que aponta ("chau" é a forma da palavra mais comum em pt-PT):

> **chau** figura igualmente no *Dicionário de Expressões Populares* (Lisboa, Edições D. Quixote, 1993)

datando a entrada de "tchau" no pt-PT como anterior à década de 1990 — mas provavelmente não muito anterior.

*Curiosidade*: a [Hemeroteca Digital](https://memoria.bn.br/hdb/periodico.aspx) do Brasil até encontra um [registro](https://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=890529&pesq=chau&hf=memoria.bn.br&pagfis=12652) no Correio da Manhã, Lisboa, de 1893 do uso da palavra "chau", mas lá trata-se claramente de uma transliteração de "ciao", não de um termo em si. A Hemeroteca brasileira encontra usos de "tchau" em jornais brasileiros já na década de 1940. Infelizmente a [Hemeroteca de Lisboa](http://hemerotecadigital.cm-lisboa.pt/) não parece proporcionar uma busca abrangente por termo.